# Knowing when a YouTube video starts playing from within a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

I have made a class that plays YouTube videos (thanks to the help from the kind people of this site).

Now I am wondering how I find out when a YouTube video starts playing. I want to know this so I can show a "Please Wait, Loading..." indicator in-between the video being told to play and it actually playing.

I start the video playing using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`, and of course there is a slight delay between me firing off the javascript command to get the video playing and the video actually playing.

I am familiar with YouTube videos and javascript, so Ive been looking at this: [ https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html ] because I am wondering if a javascript event listener inside the UIWebView could detect when a YouTube video starts playing (listening for the `onStateChange` event) and fire off an Objective C method.

Is this possible? Do UIWebViews run javascript in the same way as a web browser would?

Is there an easier / better way of doing this?

Here is my youtube class:

```
// this is the only property declared in the .h file:
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView * view

// the rest of this is the .m file:
#import "MyYouTube.h"
@interface MyYouTube()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary * contentData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWebView * webView;
@property (nonatomic) int videoOffset;
@end

@implementation MyYouTube
@synthesize view,contentData,webView,videoOffset;

- (MyYouTube*) initIntoView: (UIView*) passedView withContent: (NSDictionary*) contentDict {
    NSLog(@"YOUTUBE: begin init");
    self=[super init];
    videoOffset=0;
    view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:passedView.bounds];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    contentData=contentDict;

    NSString * compiledUrl=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://_xxx_.com/app/youtube.php?yt=%@",[contentData objectForKey:@"cnloc"]];
    NSURL * url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:compiledUrl];
    NSURLRequest * request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:passedView.bounds];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [[webView scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [[webView scrollView] setBounces:NO];
    [webView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
    [webView setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"YOUTUBE: self: %@",self);
    NSLog(@"YOUTUBE: delegate: %@",webView.delegate);

    [view addSubview:webView];
    NSLog(@"YOUTUBE: end init");
    return self;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)myWebView {
    NSLog(@"YOUTUBE: send play command");
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"playVideo(%d)", videoOffset]];
}

@end
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that this could work on iOS7 via the new [JavaScriptCore framework](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3784-javascriptcore-and-ios-7/) (although I've not personally tested it).

What I've tested though and it seems to be working fine is this approach:

Instead of registering a listener on different event changes, you could have a timer that *queries* the state of the player every second.

First, you could define some states on the player class (that would correspond to [Youtube's states](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_status)) (in header file):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, YoutubeVideoState){
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_UNSTARTED   = -1,
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_ENDED       = 0,
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_PLAYING     = 1,
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_PAUSED      = 2,
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_BUFFERING   = 3,
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_VIDEO_CUED  = 5
};
```

Then you could have a `readonly` property to get the state (also in header file):

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) YoutubeVideoState state;
```

which would be implemented like:

```
- (YoutubeVideoState)state
{
    return (YoutubeVideoState)[[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getPlayerState()"] integerValue];
}
```

Now you can just ask from your instance to get you the current state in each timer invocation like:

```
YoutubeVideoState currentState = myPlayerInstance.state;
```

and possibly decide on your next action via a `switch` or an `if` statement:

```
if (currentState == YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_PLAYING) {
    // Start your engines!
}
```

Comment: may I ask how to get the player instance? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanFeng The player instance is on the JS side, but it seems that Google now [provides a library for embedding YouTube videos in iOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) which seems to make things easier for us (haven't tested it though)